# MySQL query for fetching result

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in the database:

[image]

I need to get the row common for subcat_id=1 and subcat_id=8, i.e. the row for client_id=2.

What should be the query for that?

Edited:
  Lets say I have subcat_id 1 and 8. I need the client_id which has subcat_id 1and 8, in this case 1. I need the common client_id which lies in both subcat_id. Am I making more sense?

Comment: Image is not showing up. Please update so someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: I dont have the client_id. I need the client_id and I only have subcat_id.

Comment: Can you tidy up your question and make it more clear what you want?  For example, supposing `subcat_id` with values of 1 and 8 corresponded to 2 _different_ `client_id` values.  Then what would you do in this case?

Comment: No, it's not.  Will every `client_id` - `subcat_id` pair always be unique?

Comment: Perhaps you can try a nested query. Select a.client_id from tablename a where a.subcat_id = 1 and a.client_id in (select b.client_id from tablename b where b.subcat_id = 8). Where tablename refers to the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `WHERE` clause to restrict according to what you want:

```
SELECT t1.client_id
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2
    ON t1.client_id = t2.client_id
WHERE t1.subcat_id IN (1, 8) AND t2.subcat_id IN (1, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE client_id = 2 AND ( subcat_id = 1 OR subcat_id = 8)
```

EDIT (2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tablename b ON b.subcat_id =1
AND a.subcat_id = b.subcat_id
WHERE a.subcat_id = 8
GROUP BY a.client_id
```

Comment: I obviously dont have the client_id, else I wouldnt have asked it. I need the client_id and I only have subcat_id.

Comment: no that will give me client_id =1 and client_id=2. I need the row for client_id=2. The common row for subcat_id=1 and 8

Comment: @zomato I think I may have it now, my edit #2 should return all client_id's that have subcat_id = 1 and subcat_id = 8 in different rows